# Find null space of a Linear Transformation with a second derivative polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

How would one find the null space of a Linear Transformation of a second derivative polynomial?

Let $D:\mathcal{P}_3 \rightarrow \mathcal{P}_2$ be the linear transformation such that $Dp(t)=p^{\prime\prime}(t)$

Find null$(D)$.

Would you first find a basis of $\mathcal{P}_3$? E.g. $p(t)=\alpha t^3+\beta t^2+\gamma t + \delta$ then take the second derivative which would be $p^{\prime\prime}(t)=6\alpha t -2\beta \mid \alpha,\beta\in R$?

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is fine.

Note that the null space of $D$ is the set of polynomials $p$ from $\mathcal P$ that satisfy the equation $Dp(t) = 0$.  In other words, find the set of coefficients $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta$ such that $6\alpha\,t - 2 \beta = 0t + 0$.

In particular, you should find that the null space of $D$ is the set of polynomials of the form $\gamma t + \delta$ with $\gamma,\delta \in \Bbb R$.